# How to match the correct subnet from an ifstatement Logger

Tags: c++, linux, gtk

I am trying to match any IP address within the .12 subnet. For example any IP address between 127.0**.12**.01 - 127.0**.12**.255 (except 127.0**.12**.20). How can I specify this in an if statement?

The following is what I am working with. While this works to an extend, it does not prevent subnets below or above **.12**, which is not what I am trying to achieve.

```
int verifyIP::validIpv4Address(const std::string &ipaddress)
{
    
    if(ipaddress != "127.0.12.20")
    {
if(ipaddress <="127.0.12.255)
{
return OKAY;
}
}
else
{
        Logger("This IP is invalid: " + ipaddress);
        return INVALIDIPADRRESS;
    }

    
    }
```

I have tried adding && and || to the second if statement but it doesn't read it.

Comment: Warning: Because `ipaddress <="127.0.12.255` is string  compare you get lexicographical ordering, and 127.0.112.255 probably won't give the result you want.

Comment: Maybe this isn't the best example for subnet matching, since the entire 127.0.0.0 network is treated as the loopback address. In any case, you may find it easiest to do this with regular expressions. Seems like you want something like `127\.0\.12\.([1-9]\d?|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])`. Well, unless octets are actually specified in octal or hexadecimal, which I think might actually be valid. _e.g._ `0x7f.0.014.1` is equivalent to `127.0.12.1`

Comment: This cannot be done with plain string comparison. Regexp matching, perhaps. But the most robust solution would be to parse this down into an octet-based representation of an IPv4 address, in an `uint32_t`, at which point the check becomes a nothing-burger.

Comment: As an example, `"127 0.12.zebra"s < "127.0.12.255"s` since the space character is smaller than the period character (smaller than any printable character, in fact). Do you have a guard against this sort of bad input? It may be easier to work from such a guard than to work from scratch.